# The codex[2²⁵⁶ - 1 - uint(keccak256(1)) + 1] corresponds to slot 0. How is that possible?

Tags: arrays, storage, slots

I'm stuck with Ethernaut Alien Codex problem. I understood underflow attack except that `codex[2²⁵⁶ - 1 - uint(keccak256(1)) + 1]` corresponds to slot 0. I referred to the below tables.

| Slot # | Variable |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | contact bool(1 bytes] & owner address (20 bytes), both fit on one slot |
| 1 | codex.length |
| keccak256(1) | codex[0] |
| keccak256(1) + 1 | codex[1] |
|  |  |
| 2²⁵⁶ - 1 | codex[2²⁵⁶ - 1 - uint(keccak256(1))] |
| 0 | codex[2²⁵⁶ - 1 - uint(keccak256(1)) + 1] --> can write slot 0! |

All I know is Storage has 2²⁵⁶ slots and a dynamic array that had been attacked can control every slot in the Storage. What am I missing? The source code is below.

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import '../helpers/Ownable-05.sol';

contract AlienCodex is Ownable {

  bool public contact;
  bytes32[] public codex;

  modifier contacted() {
    assert(contact);
    _;
  }
  
  function make_contact() public {
    contact = true;
  }

  function record(bytes32 _content) contacted public {
    codex.push(_content);
  }

  function retract() contacted public {
    codex.length--;
  }

  function revise(uint i, bytes32 _content) contacted public {
    codex[i] = _content;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, we know `codex[a]` writes to slot `a + keccak(1)`, for every number `a`, since that's how solidity saves a dynamic variable.

The number `2**256 - 1 - uint(keccak256(1)) + 1` can be simplified into `2**256 - keccak(1)`, since `-1+1 = 0`. Also since `2**256 = 0` (thinking modulo `2**256`), the number becomes `-keccak(1)`.

Using `a = -keccak(1)`, we get:

```
codex[a] --->   a + keccak(1) = -keccak(1) + keccak(1) = 0
```

so we're writing to slot `0`.

Comment: Can we assume that the end and the beginning of the array are connected? It's not clear for me to understand why `2**256 = 0`.

Comment: It's more than when it's calculating the slot it overflows. Since a number can only have 256 bits, `2**256` becomes `0`. Thinking about the array may be confusing, but yeah you can say it's biting its own tail: there are only `2**256` slots, so when you go over that number you start overwriting over previous slots.